# Corona SDK Storyboard EnterScene/ExitScene

Tags: storyboard, coronasdk

I have some problems with closing Timers and Events

Here is my  enterScene(event)

```
function scene:enterScene( event )

storyboard.purgeScene("menu")

timer.performWithDelay(1, update, -1)
Runtime:addEventListener("touch", touched, -1)
yesButton:addEventListener("touch", yesListener )
noButton:addEventListener("touch", noListener )

end
```

And here is my Exit Scene(event)

```
function scene:exitScene( event )
  timer.pause()
    Runtime:removeEventListener("touch", touched, -1)
    yesButton:removeEventListener("touch", yesListener )
    noButton:removeEventListener("touch", noListener )
end
```

i have error at "time.pause()".

What is the correct syntax for closing timers and Events?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign your timer to a variable and cancel it when you want.

```
local myTimer -- Reference for the timer

function scene:enterScene(event)
    storyboard.purgeScene("menu")
    myTimer = timer.performWithDelay(1, update, -1)
    Runtime:addEventListener("touch", touched, -1)
    yesButton:addEventListener("touch", yesListener )
    noButton:addEventListener("touch", noListener )
end

function scene:exitScene(event)
    --> Cancel the timer
    timer.cancel(myTimer)

    Runtime:removeEventListener("touch", touched, -1)
    yesButton:removeEventListener("touch", yesListener )
    noButton:removeEventListener("touch", noListener )

end
```